# Calculations with Groupby objects Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to retrieve two groupby series objects and calculate between each other.

Series objects below:

```
Cost
    ID    yy
    312   13    102429.610000
    361   15    170526.000000
    373   14    400000.000000
    403   13    165000.000000
          14    165000.000000
          15    183558.720000
          16    133763.760980
          17    121301.930160

Percentage
        ID    yy
        312   13     21.687500
        361   15     33.181818
        373   14     12.439024
        403   13     22.966667
              14     22.966667
              15     24.142857
              16     23.333333
              17     36.666667

cost=df.groupby(['ID', 'yy'])['cost']
percentage=df.groupby(['ID', 'yy'])['percentage']
```

I essentially want to calculate cost * percentage.

how is this done correctly? The error is 'unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'SeriesGroupBy' and 'SeriesGroupBy'.

Comment: You're making things harder by treating two series from the same (grouped) df as two different objects. Instead do `df.groupby(['ID', 'yy'])` and save that grouped df (or use it with a context manager). See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using groupby without any aggregate function which returns as groupby object, NOT a series.

You need

```
cost = df1.set_index(['ID', 'yy'])['cost']
pct = df2.set_index(['ID', 'yy'])['cost']
cost.mul(pct/100)

ID   yy
312  13    22214.421669
361  15    56583.626963
373  14    49756.096000
403  13    37895.000550
     14    37895.000550
     15    44316.319281
     16    31211.543783
     17    44477.374796
```

Comment: No, the series are both from the same df. So you simply do `df.groupby(['ID', 'yy'])`

Comment: @smci, here cost and percentage are two different dataframes as specified in the question

Comment: no they're not, they both came from the same grouped df: `df.groupby(['ID', 'yy'])`.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need ?

```
pct.mul(cost)/100
Out[332]: 
ID   yy
312  13    22214.421669
361  15    56583.626963
373  14    49756.096000
403  13    37895.000550
     14    37895.000550
     15    44316.319281
     16    31211.543783
     17    44477.374796
Name: V, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly multiply cost and percentage just because here your indices i.e id and yy are same for both DF.
So

```
percentage.mul(cost)  should work.
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in treating two series from the same (grouped) df as two different objects. So just do:

```
with df.groupby(['ID', 'yy']) as dfg:
    dfg['cost'] * dfg['percentage'] # you have to assign or write the output
```

You can probably even reduce this to a one-liner, if you post us reproducible data I'll post it. In fact as @Neo showed, something like:

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'yy']).percentage.mul(cost)
```